# How do I set the color of the radio button's control?

Tags: codenameone

How do I set the color of the radio button's control? No matter what color I specify in the style, it draws the outer circle and inner bullet in black. I want it to draw in in white on a black background to match my theme, but it always draws in black. (I'm actually doing this in a Multi-Button, setting the color of the Emblem UIID.)

---

I tried the first suggestion, to define the constants. That didn't work. Here's what happened.

I tried it two ways. First I defined just the radioSelectedImage and radioUnselectedImage. When that didn't work, I added both the radio*DisImage values, but it did the same thing. The selected and unselected images worked fine, but as soon as I touched a radio button, it got the focus, and the button was drawn in black, which made it invisible against my black background.

I did find an approach that worked, but it required the use of two deprecated classes. Here's what I added to the init() method of my main class:

```
    LookAndFeel lookAndFeel = UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel();
    if (lookAndFeel instanceof DefaultLookAndFeel) {
        DefaultLookAndFeel defaultLookAndFeel = (DefaultLookAndFeel) lookAndFeel;
        Image sel = theme.getImage("RadioButtonSelected.png");
        Image unSel = theme.getImage("RadioButtonUnselected.png");
        defaultLookAndFeel.setRadioButtonImages(sel, unSel, sel, unSel);
        defaultLookAndFeel.setRadioButtonFocusImages(sel, unSel, sel, unSel);
    }
```

The difference here is that I have a way to set the focus images. I can't do that using the constants, which is probably why it doesn't work. I'd really rather not use deprecated classes.

Comment: Does your theme have the `includeNative` option? Does your theme define the radio button image in the theme constants?

Comment: I tried includeNativeBool both ways, and it didn't make any difference. As I pointed out in my addendum, I do have the radio* constants defined in my theme, but they don't apply when the button has the focus.

Comment: As an experiment, I removed the call to setRadioButtonFocusImages(). It behaved exactly the same way as when I didn't use the deprecated classes, but defined the four radio* constants.

Comment: If you do have the constants then you need to define all of them: `radioSelectedImage`, `radioSelectedFocusImage`, `radioUnselectedImage`, `radioUnselectedFocusImage`, `radioSelectedDisImage`, `radioSelectedDisFocusImage`, `radioUnselectedDisImage`, `radioUnselectedDisFocusImage`.

Comment: Thank you. The four constants with "Focus" inside aren't documented in the "Advanced Theming" section of the manual, and aren't choices offered by the resource editor. It might be a good idea to add them. They worked great. I was able to remove the deprecated code.

Comment: I'll add them to the next update of the developer guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are theme constants to allow you to add images to the radio button for unselected, selected, etc. Look here...

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html

Comment: First, let me say that there's a minor bug in the resource editor. When I specify a value for any of the 4 Radio* constants, the chosen value doesn't show up in the editor. Instead, it says [default value]. This is minor, because when I quit the resource editor and relaunch it, it shows me the images I've chosen. However, it doesn't work in my app as I will describe in my next comment.

Comment: Okay, I put it in the description at the top instead.

Comment: That minor bug in the resource editor was some kind of glitch. I haven't been able to reproduce it.